# Is there a performance benefit to Spark streaming application with multiple jobs (actions) vs one job?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

Given the following,

```
  /**
    * With only one job active at a time this processing can ensure that data for
    * all partitions must be written to A before B
    */
  def processWithMulitpleActions(rdd: RDD[T]): Unit = {
    val transformedRdd = rdd.mapPartitions(partition => {
      partition.map(item => item)
    })
    transformedRdd.foreachPartition(partition => {
      // writeToA(partition)
    })
    transformedRdd.foreachPartition(partition => {
      // writeToB(partition)
    })
  }

  /**
    * With only one job active at a time this processing can ensure that for any single partition
    * all data must written to A before B.
    */
  def processWithSingleAction(rdd: RDD[T]): Unit = {
    rdd.foreachPartition(partition => {
      // writeToA(partition)
      // writeToB(partition)
    })
  }
```

is there any performance benefit to running multiple jobs in Spark streaming application? Other than functional implications mentioned in my comments I don't see any benefits.

Spark streaming executes each job sequentially (one at a time) by default so what difference does it make? Theoretically processWithSingleAction should run faster then processWithMulitpleActions since the latter may have second job scheduled and executed with some delay, however, the latter may have more resources for execution.

Any thoughts here?

Comment: yes as you said processWithSingleAction will be faster and it is better to write a single job considering. if you consider overall cost of usage of cluster ***processWithSingleAction*** will make much more sense to do than other.